# Google Sheet - convert Hours & minute to seconds

Tags: regex, google-sheets, time, google-sheets-formula, number-formatting

Need to convert Hours & minutes to seconds.

Ex : 5h 30m  -> 19800
3h 15m  -> 11700

Tried to use Formatting options & the SECOND() function. But it's not working.

Comment: is "5h 30m" an accurate representation of your data? or is it "5:30"  in a cell?

Comment: Its is "5h 30m"  or "5h" in the cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have `5:30` you can do this:

```
=TEXT(A7, "[ss]")*1
```

[image]

if you have no idea use:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/TEXT(REGEXREPLACE(A7:A10&"", 
 "(\d+)h ?(\d+)m", "$1:$2")*1, "[ss]"))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Its is working for me.  But, when i change the "5h 30m"  to "5h" its returning empty result.

Comment: @ChamaraMaduranga try: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVOa3.png

Answer (score 1):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=INDEX(IF(A1:A<>"",--REGEXREPLACE(A1:A,"(\d+)h +(\d+)m","$1:$2"),""))
```

Custom numberformat in `B:B` is `[ss]`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should also work:

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(SPLIT(S4,"hm"),{3600,60}),SPLIT(S4,"h")*3600)
```

[image: Potential Solution]